# Gcc x64 function calling

Tags: c++, gcc, 64-bit, convention, abi

As far as I know, there are two possible calling conventions for the `x64` code - `Microsoft x64` and `AMD64`.

Now, `gcc` can be launched with the `-mregparm=0` parameter, which doesn't work if we are working using the `AMD64` calling convention. *This happens because the `AMD64` convention mandates the usage of the registers for the first 6 variables* (I'm not really sure why this is done, but I suspect it's implemented due do possibly stack security issues).

**So, here is the question:**

Are there some strict rules like this *(forced register usage)* when compiling using `gcc` under `Microsoft x64` convention? And, if yes, how can they be bypassed without breaking the `ABI` compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Microsoft Windows (and never used it), so I probably cannot answer your question about it.

However, the AMD64 Application Binary Interface calling conventions (On Linux and other Unixes) are documented in the [AMD64 ABI spec](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (maybe you should also find and read the equivalent document for Microsoft calling conventions). I believe they are using registers for the 6 first arguments because of performance considerations (passing values thru register is faster than passing them on the stack), not because of security considerations.

And whatever C++ compiler you use, you want it to follow some calling conventions, and these are practically dictated by the system (because you want to be able to call system libraries from your code). So if you break them, you will break the ABI compatibility.

But I cannot guess why are asking such a question. Are you developing a compiler with its own calling conventions? If yes, you still should have some means to call C libraries, and this required that for call to external C libraries, you follow the ABI conventions governing them. Look into the Ocaml compiler for an example.

Comment: *Just being curious.* I've been doing some optimization research for `x64` platforms and wanted to resolve some certain misunderstanding with the calling conventions.

Comment: See this answer for accessible documents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/2165903

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can bypass these without breaking ABI. A function call and how that affects registers etc. is a fundamental part of the platform ABI.

Chances are your program will not work on Windows x64 due to a mismatched function call ABI.

For all the documentation you could want, see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I guess you're correct. However *(just for me to know)* - does the `MS64 convention` have the same rules about mandatory usage of the registers (as `AMD64`)? Or in `MS64` you are free to choose between the stack and the registers?