# GCC-Assemby Error: Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data'

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, elf, relocation

## Situation

---

1. #### Enviroment

   > Arch Linux x86-64 (4.2.3-1-ARCH)
2. #### GCC

   > gcc (GCC) 5.2.0
3. #### Command

   > ```
   > gcc -Wall -g -o asm_printf asm_printf.s
   > ```
4. #### Error

   > ```
   > /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cct4fa.o: Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
   > /tmp/cct4fa.o:err adding symbols: Bad value
   > collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   > ```
5. #### Code

   > ```
   > .section .data
   > msg:
   >     .asciz "Printf In Assembly!!\n"
   >
   > .section .text
   > .globl main
   > main:
   >     pushq $msg
   >     call printf
   >     addq $8 %esp
   >
   >     pushq $0
   >     call exit
   > ```

---

## Question

---

I tried to use `gcc` to compile the program in the above **Code** section using the command in the above **Command** section and ended up with a error in the **Error** Section.

> **Note** that I am **not** compiling a shared library.

1. What is this error?
2. How do i fix this?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific error is due to the `push` instruction only supporting 32 bit immediates and you tried to use that for a 64 bit address.

However, the whole code is wrong. It's unclear whether you want 32 or 64 bit code. Most of the code seems to be 32 bit, except for the `pushq` so I assume you really wanted 32 bit code. For that, change all those to `push` (which is a good idea anyway) and compile using `gcc -m32`. Also, you only need to remove 4 bytes from the stack, so use `addl $4, %esp`. (Thanks to *@Employed Russian* for pointing this out.)

The 64 bit calling convention is different from 32 bit, so to create a 64 bit version you must make more changes. Since I assume you really wanted 32 bit, here it is for illustration only:

```
.section .data
msg:
    .asciz "Printf In Assembly!!\n"

.section .text
.globl main
main:
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq msg(%rip), %rdi
    xor %al, %al
    call printf

    xor %edi, %edi
    call exit
```

Comment: For 32-bit code, stack cleanup after `CALL` also needs to change from 8 to 4.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Even if it makes no difference here :)

Comment: @Jester, I cannot find any book about GAS asm for x64. There are only for 32bit. And as I see from example, the 'hello world' in x64 and 32 is COMPLETELY different. (e.g. no push immediate for fd, syscall and others). So where can I find good book or resource for x64 asm? Also, I want to learn x64 for kernel syscall and the for drive development, but does actually kernel use x64 asm or 32bit in his *.S files? How will differ 32bit asm from x64 in real use?

Comment: 64 bit kernel uses 64 bit asm. Drivers don't use asm. The calling convention and other low level stuff is defined in the [x86-64 abi pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812/547981). system calls and arguments are described in the kernel source or [online tables](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64).