# Relocation R_X86_64_32S against .data cannot be used when making a shared object (64 bit NASM + gcc)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, nasm, libc

I'm trying to make a program with NASM and GCC:

```
global main
extern puts

section .data
  hi db 'hello', 0

section .text
main:
  push hi
  call puts
  ret
```

I am building with:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.asm
gcc main.o -o main
rm main.o
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have a feeling I'm doing a few things wrong, judging by the presence of weird stack operations in examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476098/gcc-assemby-error-relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-data) and [this](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample_64.shtml#fib_64m.asm). I can't find any documentation that actually *explains* this, for some reason, though (In fact, I can hardly find any useful documentation for 64-bit development with NASM in general, which has made everything I've made so far a real pain in the ass to make), and adding in things like that don't have any effect on my error output.

**Update:**

I've been looking at [this](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071280/nasm-symbol-printf-causes-overflow-in-r-x86-64-pc32-relocation).

If I change my main to:

```
  push rbp
  mov rax,0
  mov rdi, hi
  call [puts wrt ..got]
  pop rbp
  mov rax,0

  ret
```

It compiles fine, but then gives me a segfault when running instead of actually printing. I also don't understand why I'm pushing and pulling the value of `rbp` from the stack, and why `rax`'s value matters in this case.

Comment: Also see [Access .data section in Position Independent Code (PIC)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36223182/608639) and [Writing NetBSD/FreeBSD/OpenBSD and Linux/ELF Shared Libraries](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.f04/nasmdoc/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.2) in the NASM manual.

Comment: Related: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) / [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rbp` is a callee-saved register hence you need to preserve it. You are not changing it so you don't have to `push`/`pop` it here. However you need to preserve 16 byte stack alignment, and a `push` is a simple way to do that. You could have used any other register, or even `sub rsp, 8`.

`mov rdi, hi` should be `lea rdi, [rel hi]`.

Functions are called through the PLT not the GOT, and not through a pointer. Just do `call puts ..wrt plt`.

As such, the following should work:

```
global main
extern puts

section .data
  hi db 'hello', 0

section .text
main:
  push rbp
  lea rdi, [rel hi]
  call puts wrt ..plt
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Comment: Excellent, it works! Might I ask where you learned this? I've been struggling to find a good guide for 64-bit NASM with libc.

Comment: `call [puts wrt ..got]` is also correct; it's the NASM equivalent of `gcc -fno-plt` code-gen.  [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131094) shows both options, inlining the indirect call through the GOT or just calling the PLT stub.   (@EthanMcTague)