# Get argv[2] address in assembler x64

Tags: assembly

edi is argc, rsi is argv

```
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400538 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
```

here I get argv pointer

```
(gdb) x/8x $rbp-0x10
0x7ffdb7cac380: 0xb7cac478  0x00007ffd  0x00000000  0x00000003
0x7ffdb7cac390: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x1f130b45  0x00007ff3
```

Pointer 0x7ffdb7cac478

So my argv[2] is here:

```
(gdb) x/8x 0x7ffdb7cac478+16
0x7ffdb7cac488: 0xb7cacd8a  0x00007ffd  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

At address 0x7ffdb7cacd8a

I need to get the address of argv[2], so I want to write this assembler code:

Pseudocode:

x - load 8 bytes from address $rbp-0x10  // (pointer to argv)

y - load 8 bytes from x value+16 // (pointer to argv[2])

I need later to jmp to y.

How do I write in assembler x64? Which register I can use to for x and y?

I hope it is understandable. I am a beginner.

I ask here since I don't know where to start doing my research.

**UPDATE:**

Tried with this:

```
bits 64
ldr r8, rbp, #0x10
ldr r9, r8, #0x10
jmp r9
```

But it doesn't even compile .... I am using nasm.

I guess above was for ARM arch, for amd64 (x64) below should do this. Is it correct?

**UPDATE 2:**

```
bits 64
lea r8, [rbp-0x10]
lea r9, [r8+0x10]
jmp r9
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Also doesn't work ...

```
bits 64
lea r8, [rbp-0x10]
mov r9, [r8]
mov r10, [r9+0x10]
jmp r10
```

Comment: Nothing beats reading about registers and program flow from your favorite assembler reference. For which registers to use for `x and y` you could use any two general purpose registers. For "How do I do this", the answer is try and then post your progress if you get stuck.

Comment: These are my first assembler steps, dont have any favorite reference. Can you point to any? A big help would be to at least tell which instruction load x bytes to an address ? Is it ldr, ldi ? What should I search for?

Comment: Added my code I tried ... doesn't even compile :/

Comment: added another code ... this compiles, but not sure if it is correct

Comment: Try http://www.nasm.us/doc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you writing `main()` or `_start`?

If you're writing `main`, it's a normal function with its args in `rdi`, `rsi`, following the normal calling convention.  See [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links [to the x86-64 ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented).

If you're writing `_start`, then data is on the stack, as documented in process startup section of the ABI: `[rsp] = argc`, and above that an array of pointers, `char *arg[]` starting at `rsp+8`.  It's an actual array right there on the stack, not a *pointer to* an array like `main` gets.

`rbp` is meaningless unless you initialize it.  It has whatever the caller left in it.

---

Your code fragment is silly, too: you never initialize rbp.  You should assume it holds garbage on process entry.  Only `rsp` is guaranteed to be useful.

`lea` is just a shift & add instruction that uses effective-address syntax / encoding.  `mov` is the mnemonic for load / store.

```
    ;; your code with comments, also assuming that RBP was initialized
    bits 64
    lea r8, [rbp-0x10]      ; r8 = rbp-0x10
    mov r9, [r8]            ; should have just done mov r9, [rbp-0x10]
    mov r10, [r9+0x10]
    jmp r10                 ; jump to argv[2]???
```

Did you put machine code bytes in `argv[2]`?  Jumping to a string is not normally useful.

Of course, since `rbp` isn't initialized, it's not actually accessing `argv[2]`.

---

### Working example

single-step this in a debugger if you want to see what's going on.

```
; get argc and argv from the stack, for x86-64 SysV ABI
global _start
_start:
    mov   ecx,  [rsp]             ;   load argc (assuming it's smaller than 2^32)

    cmp   ecx, 3
    jb  .argc_below_3
                                  ;   argv[0] is at rsp+8
    mov   rsi,  [rsp+8 +  8*2]    ;   argv[2]  (the 3rd element)
    movzx eax,  byte [rsi]        ;   first char of argv[2]

    ; if you stop here in a debugger, you can see the character from the second arg.

    ; fall through and exit
.argc_below_3:
    xor edi, edi
    mov eax, 231                  ;  exit_group(0)
    syscall
```

Comment: Can you add how to access the `char** argv` params if we are writing for `main()` linux 64. or if it is possible to point me to some documentation where I can get this info? thank you for your time.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout: on entry to `main`, RSI = argv like I mention in this answer.  See also [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) which covers the function-calling convention as well.  Or look at compiler-generated code for a C `main` if you aren't sure how to use it in some specific way: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: thank you Peter for your response. I have been looking for four hours now for this (second day). I have managed to find a way to convert a c prog to nasm readable format using objconv lib. how ever I really do not see it. All I need is a way to read the cmmand line passed to my main() that are stored in argv. I know that they are in RSI but I'm failing to get them. I would kindly ask you to point me to an easy way to understand how to retrieve that info from RSI in 64 linux.

Comment: I think I found it. thank you so much for your help. If you have any info (pitfalls that I might encounter) please share. again thank so much for your help. for any one that having the same problem see [this post](https://sinister.ly/Thread-ASM-How-to-get-command-line-arguments) your first argv[1] is at qword [rsi+8] (linux 64)

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout: Yup, that's right.  There's an FAQ section in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info where I've already covered various common pitfalls that people often post questions about.  By far the most important skill is using a debugger like GDB to single-step and watch registers / memory change.  With that and an instruction set reference, you're all set to figure out how / why anything else works.  (And `strace ./my_program` to trace system calls and make sure you got the args right.)