# What sret actually means?

Tags: c, llvm, abi

I compared 2 C functions returning a struct. We know that on ABI level big structs are going to be passes by pointer as the first function argument.

```
struct S {
    int words[8];
};

struct S fsret() {
    struct S s;
    s.words[0] = 1;
    return s;
}

void fout(struct S* s) {
    s->words[0] = 1;
}
```

For these functions I checked the assembly for x86_64 Linux and Windows. The `fsret` is declared as `void @fsret(%struct.S* sret %s)`.

Comparing these two variants, there is no difference on the callee side. However, inside the functions the `fsret` additionally copies its first argument (the pointer to the struct) to the RAX register. Why?

Comment: what if you do `if (fsret().words[0]==10) { do_something(); }` ? the compiler needs a return value in that case (not sure, just an idea)

Answer (score 6):

The reason lies in [this](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20150511/276045.html) review diff:

```
if (Subtarget->is64Bit() || Subtarget->isTargetKnownWindowsMSVC()) {
  for (unsigned i = 0, e = ArgLocs.size(); i != e; ++i) {
    // The x86-64 ABIs require that for returning structs by value we copy
    // the sret argument into %rax/%eax (depending on ABI) for the return.
    // Win32 requires us to put the sret argument to %eax as well.
    // Save the argument into a virtual register so that we can access it
    // from the return points.
```

so the callee has to fill the memory supplied by the caller **and** return the pointer that it was passed as well.

This is confirmed by the [x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/1938163) r252 System V ABI document

> Returning of Values The returning of values is done according to the following
>   algorithm:
>
> 1. Classify the return type with the classification algorithm.
> 2. If the type has class MEMORY *(ndMarco: i.e. big stuff)*, then the caller provides space for the return
>      value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first
>      argument to the function. In effect, this address becomes a “hidden” first argument.
>      This storage must not overlap any data visible to the callee through
>      other names than this argument.
>      **On return %rax will contain the address that has been passed in by the
>      caller in %rdi.**

Comment: Great answer! Do you know if there are similar requirements for other targets?

Comment: @PawełBylica [o32 and eabi](http://www.brunocardoso.cc/blog/?p=27), many ABI documentations are rather poor