# Required alignment of .text versus .data

Tags: linux, x86, elf

I've been toying around with the [ELFIO](http://elfio.sourceforge.net/) library. [One of the examples](https://sourceforge.net/p/elfio/code/ci/master/tree/examples/writer/writer.cpp), in particular, allows one to create an ELF file from scratch – defining sections, segments, entry point, and providing binary content to the relevant sections.

I noticed that a program created this way segfaults when the code segment alignment is chosen less than the page size (0x1000):

```
// Create a loadable segment
segment* text_seg = writer.segments.add();
text_seg->set_type( PT_LOAD );
text_seg->set_virtual_address( 0x08048000 );
text_seg->set_physical_address( 0x08048000 );
text_seg->set_flags( PF_X | PF_R );
text_seg->set_align( 0x1000 ); // can't change this
```

NB that the `.text` *section* is only aligned to multiples of 0x10 in the same example:

```
section* text_sec = writer.sections.add( ".text" );
text_sec->set_type( SHT_PROGBITS );
text_sec->set_flags( SHF_ALLOC | SHF_EXECINSTR );
text_sec->set_addr_align( 0x10 );
```

However, the data segment, although loaded separately through the same mechanism, does not have this problem:

```
segment* data_seg = writer.segments.add();
data_seg->set_type( PT_LOAD );
data_seg->set_virtual_address( 0x08048020 );
data_seg->set_physical_address( 0x08048020 );
data_seg->set_flags( PF_W | PF_R );
data_seg->set_align( 0x10 ); // note here!
```

Now in this specific case the data fits by design within the page that's already allocated. Not sure if this makes any difference, but I changed its virtual address to 0x8148020 and the result still works fine.

Here's the output of `readelf`:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000008048000 0x0000000008048000
                 0x000000000000001d 0x000000000000001d  R E    1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001020 0x0000000008148020 0x0000000008148020
                 0x000000000000000e 0x000000000000000e  RW     10
```

**Why does the program fail to execute when the alignment of the executable segment is not a multiple of 0x1000 but for data 0x10 is no problem?**

---

**Update:** Somehow on a second try `text_seg->set_align( 0x100 );` works too, `text_seg->set_align( 0x10 );` fails. The page size is 0x1000 and interestingly, the working program's `VirtAddr` does not adhere to it in either segment:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000100 0x08048100 0x08048100 0x0001d 0x0001d R E 0x100
  LOAD           0x000120 0x08148120 0x08148120 0x0000e 0x0000e RW  0x10
```

The SIGSEGV'ing one:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000080 0x08048100 0x08048100 0x0001d 0x0001d R E 0x10
  LOAD           0x0000a0 0x08148120 0x08148120 0x0000e 0x0000e RW  0x10
```

Resulting ELFs are [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51374494465381092866).

Comment: Can you post both resulting .ELF files?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Sure. I must have made a mistake, 0x100 works, too. But 0x10 still breaks. Page size is 0x1000. Here are the two files for comparison, with a few more address tweaks to make them smaller: [(tinyupload.com)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51374494465381092866)

Comment: You need to *carefully* read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html). IMHO both  code and data segments should be page-aligned, and the fact that `execve` sometimes deals with unaligned segments is an implementation detail (and might change in future kernels, or future x86-64 processors), perhaps even an undefined behavior. BTW, the question is both linux and processor (ISA) specific.

Comment: If you need to understand *why* the kernel is behaving like you observe, you should dive into the kernel source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ELF ABI does not require that `VirtAddr` or `PhysAddr` be page-aligned. (I believe) it only requires that

```
({Virt,Phys}Addr - Offset) % PageSize == 0
```

That is true for both working binaries, and false for the non-working one.

**Update:**

> I don't see how this fails for the latter.

We have: `VirtAddr == 0x08048100` and `Offset == 0x80` (and `PageSize == 4096 == 0x1000`).

```
(0x08048100 - 0x80) % 0x1000 == 0x80 != 0
```

> has to agree when align == 0x10, doesn't it?

No: it has to agree with the page size (as I said earlier), or the kernel will not be able to `mmap` the segment.

Comment: I don't see how this fails for the latter. Only the last nibble (0x0) has to agree when align == 0x10, doesn't it?

Comment: Ooh, I see, I've substituted "alignment" in my head. This makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Why must they be congruent? That part is confusing me

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(sorry, more an extended comment than an answer)</sup>

There are some specifications about what an ELF executable should be. Read in particular [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and most importantly the relevant [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812/841108) question), e.g. on https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI

AFAIU, these specifications require both code and data segments to be page-aligned, but you need to check that, notably in chapter 5 (program loading and dynamic linking) of the ABI spec.

Current tools generating ELF executables (notably [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) are working hard to respect these specifications. If you code some ELF generator, you should also try hard to respect these specifications (so testing that the generated ELF apparently works is *not* enough).

The kernel is implementing [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), and [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) is done also with [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). For some reasons (performance probably) it does not check that an executable obeys all the specifications.

<sup>(of course, kernel folks want commonly produced ELF executables to be successfully `execve`-d)</sup>

In some corner cases (like the one you observe) the kernel is not failing `execve`  and doing something with ill-constructed ELF files.

But IMHO there is no guarantee about that. Future kernels, and future x86-64 processors, might fail on such ill-constructed ELF files.

My feeling is that you are in some grey area, a bit some "undefined behavior" of `execve`. If it happens to work, it is by bad luck.

> Why does the program fail to execute when the alignment of the executable segment is not a multiple of 0x1000 but for data 0x10 is no problem?

To understand precisely why, you need to dive into the source code (related to `execve`) of your particular kernel. And I believe that it might perhaps change in the future (future versions of the kernel).

The kernel community is more or less promising past-compatibility, but this is with the *specification*. It could happen that some ill-formed ELF executable could be `execve`-d by Linux 3.10 but not by Linux 4.13 or some future Linux 5.

<sup>(I did read that some past kernels have been able to `execve`-d some ill formed ELF executables, but I forgot the details, perhaps something related to the 16 bytes alignment of stack pointers)</sup>

Comment: That must be it. I especially like the rationale behind the possibility of not checking otherwise required restrictions for performance reasons. I think the source of my confusion was that the example program of ELFIO was not compliant – I'll double check your suggested sources and alert the developer.

Comment: What developer would you alert? ELFIO is not required to check everything. *You*, the one using ELFIO to emit ELF files, should work hard to follow the ELF specifications.

Comment: That's right, but I *suspect* that the data segment in [their own example](https://sourceforge.net/p/elfio/code/ci/master/tree/examples/writer/writer.cpp) has some further problems. It's aligned to 0x10, which is certainly less than the page size on any x86 (starting at 0x(...)020), and, more importantly, overlaps with the code segment, so that would require RW permissions on a part of memory that had already been allocated with RX. Compliance is up to the users of the library, of course, but an example provided alongside should not mislead users (if my suspicion proves right).

Comment: So it would be a documentation bug.

Comment: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html makes a tiny 45-byte ELF static executable by overlapping the program header with the ELF header.  It says that Linux happens to ignore the `p_align` field in the `phdr` for non-relocatable ELF executables, and some other specifics of what fields can/can't be garbage for current Linux.  Is this related to what you were thinking of with the last footnote?, Basile?  (@TheVee, you might also want to check it out)