# Function called in a file without a prototype produce different results on ARM and x86-64

Tags: c, arm, x86-64

We have 3 files: `main.c`, `lib.h` and `lib.c`:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* #include "lib.h" */

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof unsigned long long: %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));
    printf("sizeof int: %zu\n", sizeof(int));
    unsigned long long slot = 0;
    int pon_off = 1;
    lib_fn(slot, pon_off);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

lib.h:

```
void lib_fn(unsigned slot, int pon_off);
```

lib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void lib_fn(unsigned slot, int pon_off)
{
    printf("slot: %d\n", slot);
    printf("pon_off: %d\n", pon_off);
    return;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra main.c lib.c
```

Run on ARM:

```
$ ./a.out
sizeof unsigned long long: 8
sizeof int: 4
slot: 0
pon_off: 0
```

Run on x86-64:

```
$ ./a.out
sizeof unsigned long long: 8
sizeof int: 4
slot: 0
pon_off: 1
```

As you see `pon_off` is 0 on ARM but 1 on x86-64.  I guess it has
something to do with arguments size as `lib_fn()` takes two ints that
are together 8 bytes long and a single `long long` is 8 bytes long.

1. Why is `pon_off` printed differently on ARM and x86-64?
2. Does it have something to do with a calling convention?

Comment: It has everything to do with not providing the function prototype. Please do that and move on. "I don't tie my shoelaces. That's OK with my BB's but not with my Sharks. Why is that?"  Answer: tie your shoelaces.

Comment: @WeatherVane Still, it is interesting to know why, and sometimes these knowledges helps you debugging code.

Comment: Your compiler has probably wept. Don't torture it, it is your friend.

Comment: @klutt what you say is especially true if the fault is a side-effect of the actual bug, and you want to assure yourself that the bug really was the cause, and not just another "bump under the carpet that moves when you whack it".

Comment: I was expecting some hints but everyone just said that I should not know what's the reason. That's sad.

Comment: I guess this behavior has to have something to do with `ABI`. I know that adding a function prototype fixes the problem, I'm not that stupid.

Comment: Doesn't the answer help? These are comments.

Comment: No, @user1042840, it's not sad.  You are dabbling in undefined behavior.  At the level of the C language, then, *there is no reason*.  To the extent that there is any definedness at all, it is tied up in hardware and software implementation details.  For the purpose of learning to write solid, reliable, portable C programs, the lesson is simple: avoid exercising undefined behaviors.

Comment: I tagged the question with `x86-64` and `ARM` and mentioned calling convention as a possible explanation because I realize that hardware matters.

Comment: C aims to be hardware independent, it's classified as a high-level language but at the same time it has dozens of implementation-defined and unspecified rules and depends on hardware a lot.

Comment: C is a low level language, just above assembler.

Comment: I have never heard anyone saying that C is a `low level` language. You're the first.

Comment: It was developed by people who wrote assembly code, to make their life easier.

Comment: I know. But what's the point?

Comment: The point of what?

Comment: Of you bringing up the C history?

Comment: C *is* hardware independent in it's *defined* scope. When you are entering the undefined one, it might depend on anything.

Comment: Because you challenged my assertion that C is a low level language. It might have been considered to be a high level language once, but more than 40 years' water has flowed under the bridge since.

Comment: ... as such, C is every bit as dangerous as assembly language, but is protected to some extent by a good compiler, plus whatever hardware protection is offered (as with assembly).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The OP is saying it's sad that people are just saying "it's UB, you shouldn't be interested in the asm level explanation of what *did* happen".  There is a simple and moderately interesting answer here.  (And understanding it could help you recognize the symptoms of the same problem in the future.)  I wouldn't be surprised if this has already been asked, I should have looked for a duplicate.  OTOH, I'm just going to go out on a limb and guess that if there is one, the answer isn't as detailed as mine :P  I seem to have gotten a bit verbose here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it have something to do with a calling convention?

Yes, it has *everything* to do with the calling convention / ABI.

On x86-64, the "natural" width of a function argument is 64 bits, and narrower integer args still use a whole "slot".  (First [6 integer/pointer args and first 8 FP args in registers (SysV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) or first 4 args (Windows), then stack).

On ARM, the register width (and "arg slot" minimum width on the stack) is 32 bits, and 64-bit integer args take two registers.

On 32-bit x86 (`gcc -m32`) you would see the same behaviour as 32-bit ARM.  On AArch64, you would see the same behaviour as x86-64, because their calling conventions are all "normal" and don't pack separate narrow args into single registers.  ([x86-64 System V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-abi-documented) does pack struct members into up to 2 registers, though, instead of using a separate register per member!)

Having a minimum "arg slot" width that's equal to the register size is nearly universal, whether args are passed in registers or on the stack.  This isn't necessarily the width of `int`, though: [AVR (8-bit RISC microcontroller) has 16-bit `int` which takes two registers, but `char` / `uint8_t` args can be passed in a single register.](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Calling_Convention)

---

With a prototype, wider/narrower types are converted to what the callee expects, according to the types in the prototype.  So obviously everything works.

**Without a prototype, the type of the expression in the call determines how the arg is passed.  `unsigned long long slot` takes the first 2 arg-passing registers in ARM's calling convention, where `lib_fn` expects to find its 2 integer args.**

(The answer claiming everything is converted to `int` without a prototype is wrong.  No prototype is equivalent to `int lib_fn(...);`, but `printf` still works with `double` and `int64_t`.  Note that `float` is implicitly converted to `double` when passing to a variadic function, just like narrower integer types are up-converted to `int`, which is why `%f` is the format for `double`, and there is no format for `float`, unlike with scanf where you pass pointers.  That's just how C is designed; there's no reason for it.  But anyway, C requires that wider types are able to be passed as is to variadic functions, and all calling conventions accomodate that.)

---

BTW, **other breakage is possible**: Some implementations use a different calling convention for variadic (and thus unprototyped) functions than for normal functions.

For example, on Windows you can set some compilers to default to [the `_stdcall` calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall), where the callee pops the args from the stack.  (i.e. with a `ret 8` to do `esp+=8` after popping the return address.)  But obviously this calling convention isn't usable for variadic functions, so the default doesn't apply to them, and they would use `_cdecl` or something where the caller is responsible for cleaning up stack args, because only the caller knows for sure how many args they passed.  Hopefully in this mode compilers would at least warn if not error for implicitly declared functions, because getting it wrong leads to a crash (stack pointing to the wrong place after a call).

---

## Let's have a look at the asm for this case

For an introduction to reading compiler asm output, see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output), and especially Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).

To make the asm as simple as possible, I removed the printing and put the code in a function that returns void.  (This allows [tail-call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#In_assembly) where you jump to the function and *it* returns to your caller.)  The only instructions in the compiler output are the arg setup and jumping to lib_fn.

```
#ifdef USE_PROTO
void lib_fn(unsigned slot, int pon_off);
#endif

void foo(void) {
    unsigned long long slot = 0;
    int pon_off = 1;
    lib_fn(slot, pon_off);
}
```

**[See the source+asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'//%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A//%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A//+-mno-thumb-interwork+allows+optimized+tail-calls%0A%0A//+before+the+prototype%0Avoid+foo(void)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+long+long+slot+%3D+0%3B%0A++++int+pon_off+%3D+1%3B%0A++++lib_fn_noproto(slot,+pon_off)%3B%0A%0A++++//+break+the+calling+convention+for+64-bit%0A++++//+by+passing+a+128-bit+integer.%0A++++//lib_fn_noproto((unsigned+__int128)slot,+pon_off)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+use+this+with+/+without+-DUSE_PROTOTYPE%0A//+to+use+the+diff+feature+between+two+compiler+windows.%0A//%23ifdef+USE_PROTO%0Avoid+lib_fn(unsigned+slot,+int+pon_off)%3B%0A//%23endif%0A%0A//+after+prototype%0Avoid+bar(void)%0A%7B%0A//++++printf(%22sizeof+unsigned+long+long:+%25zu%5Cn%22,+sizeof(unsigned+long+long))%3B%0A//++++printf(%22sizeof+int:+%25zu%5Cn%22,+sizeof(int))%3B%0A++++unsigned+long+long+slot+%3D+0%3B%0A++++int+pon_off+%3D+1%3B%0A++++lib_fn(slot,+pon_off)%3B%0A++++//return+EXIT_SUCCESS%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.97457681324913,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-DUSE_PROTO+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3+-marm+-mno-thumb-interwork',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:34.23917101338947,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.01271159337544,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-DUSE_PROTO+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-DUSE_PROTO+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)',t:'0')),header:(),k:34.01271159337544,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.01271159337544,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), for ARM, x86-64, and x86-32 (`-m32`) with gcc 6.3**.  (I actually copied `foo` and renamed `lib_fn` so it would have no prototype in one version of the caller, instead of having 2 separate compiler windows for each architecture.  In a more complex case, that would be handy because you can diff between compiler panes).

For x86-64, the output is basically the same with/without the prototype.  Without, the caller has to zero `al` ([using `xor eax,eax` to zero the whole RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)) to indicate that this variadic function call is passing no FP args in XMM registers.  (In the Windows calling convention, you wouldn't have that because the Windows convention is optimized for variadic functions and simplicity of implementing them at the expense of normal functions.)

**For ARM:**

```
foo:                  @ no prototype
    mov     r2, #1    @ pon_off
    mov     r0, #0    @ slot low half
    mov     r1, #0    @ slot high half
    b       lib_fn_noproto


bar:                  @ with proto, u long long is converted to unsigned according to C rules, like the callee expects
    mov     r1, #1
    mov     r0, #0
    b       lib_fn
```

lib_fn is expecting `slot` in R0 and `pon_off` in R1.

---

### Breaking x86-64

You'd have the same problem on x86-64 if you used `unsigned __int128`.

```
lib_fn_noproto((unsigned __int128)slot, pon_off);
```

compiles to:

```
    mov     edx, 1          # pon_off = EDX = 1
    xor     edi, edi        #  low half of slot = RDI = 0
    xor     esi, esi        # high half of slot = RSI = 0
    xor     eax, eax        # number of xmm register args = 0
    jmp     lib_fn_noproto
```

which breaks the calling convention in *exactly* the same way as for 32-bit ARM with a 64-bit arg taking the first 2 slots.

Answer (score 1):

This is because how x64-86 and ARM are passing arguments to functions (as Peter Cordes mentioned in his comment).

Please compare generated assembly on [ARM](https://godbolt.org/g/QYvMnL) and on [x64-86](https://godbolt.org/g/BFBVW9):

1. On ARM unsigned long long is stored in 2 registers and int in 1, on x86 both are stored in 64-bit registers.
2. On ARM, function, when getting arguments, is reading single register for each argument making high and low part of 1st variable to be split into 2 arguments. 2nd argument passed is, in the end, omitted. On x64-86 it is still getting values from those two 64-bit registers.

Side note: on x64-86 only few starting function arguments are passed by registers, if there are more, next arguments are stored on stack.

Comment: Actually, on x86-64, arguments are passed in registers, not on the stack -- it's just that they are 64 bit registers, so each argument only takes 1.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: You are right, I edited the answer to make it correct.

Comment: @nowaqq: On x86-64 ABI for Windows, the first four arguments are passed in registers, in System V ABI for x86-64 even more (six?). Many functions only have 4 arguments or less.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no function prototype and implicit declaration is used, compiler assumes that all parameters are of type `int`.

Looks like int is different on arm and on x64-86 architecutre.

Note that modifier `%d` can only be used with int parameter, for unsigned one use `%u`

Thats why there are warnings for you.

Comment: `int` is the same on ARM and x86-64; the difference is in how wider args are passed.  On x86-64, `unsigned long long` still fits in a single register, so implicit-`int` doesn't break the calling convention.  (Because the compiler happens not to leave any high garbage in the arg-passing registers)

Comment: Sorry but it's not an answer for my question. @PeterCordes: thanks for this comment.  Are registers a possible explanation for that behavior? Can you say more about that?

Comment: @user1042840: yes, the answer should be obvious if you look at the asm with/without a prototype.  (e.g. put your code on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and diff it).

Comment: Variadic / unprototyped functions don't convert all the args to `int`.  That's not how C works; narrower args are promoted to `int`, but wider ones are passed as-is.  This is why it's possible to print `uint64_t` with `printf`.