# Non-used Reservated Stack in Intel x86 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, stack

I am in the beginning of learning intel's x86 assembly code and compiled this simple "hello world" c program (without the cfi additions for simplicity):
    #include

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {      

    printf("hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

The following x86 code came out:

```
.file   "helloworld.c"
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section    .rodata
.LC0:
.string "hello world!"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
push    rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16
mov DWORD PTR -4[rbp], edi
mov QWORD PTR -16[rbp], rsi
lea rdi, .LC0[rip]
mov eax, 0
call    printf@PLT
mov eax, 0
leave
ret
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Debian 7.2.0-19) 7.2.0"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The question: Why are those 16 bytes for local variables reserved on the stack but aren't used in any way? The program even does the same, without those lines, so for which reason were they created?

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization. Even so, you will still have padding for alignment. See the calling convention documentation.

Comment: 12 of the bytes are used to spill `argc` and `argv`; notice the two stores.  They're dead stores because you compiled in debug mode, but that's the whole point of debug mode: keep everything in memory.

Comment: thx, I understand. How can I compile it optimized? Using -o didn't help. And if 12 bytes are used for argc and argv, what are the other 4 bytes for?

Comment: Use `-O2` (capital letter). As I said, calling convention mandates alignment, so you may still have unused padding bytes.

Comment: thanks guys, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Shouldn't those 12 bytes for function parameters be reserved before calling `main`? Aren't they addressed using `rbp+x` while local variables are stored at `rbp-x`

Comment: @Gerhardh: They're passed in registers.  x86-64 calling conventions pass the first few integer args in registers, unlike some crappy obsolete 32-bit calling conventions that pass all the args on the stack.  In this case, it's the x86-64 System V ABI.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I see. Thanks

Comment: @Gerhardh As far as I understand argc and argv are still treated like parameters and parameters are reserved in the callee and main is the callee in this situation.

Comment: Args that couldn't be passed in registers are placed on the stack by the caller, but they're *owned* by the callee (i.e. functions are allowed to modify their args on the stack).  So in that case, they can't be "reserved" by the callee.  In both normal x86-64 calling conventions, the caller is responsible for un-reserving the the arg-passing space after the callee returns, though.