# Rotate Function in x86_64 AT&T assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I am implementing a rotate function in AT&T 64 bit assembly and am having trouble getting the correct output in my code.

The function I'm trying to implement is

```
unsigned long rotate(unsigned long val, ul num, ul dir);
```

`Val` is value I wanted rotated, `num` is how many times and direction is left or right, 0 being right, 1 being left.

My assembly code:

```
.global rotate

rotate: #value = %rdi
        #num = %rsi 
        #direction = %rdx 
        mov %rsi, %r10 #puts num into register
        test %rdx, %rdx 
        jz right #if rdx is 0 jump to rotate right
        #else go to loop right below which rotates left
loop: 
     test %r10, %r10 #if num is 0 I am done
     jz done 
     rol $1, %rdi #rotate left 1 bit
     dec %r10 #decrement my count
     jmp loop #jump to top of loop 

 right: #same logic as left 
      test %r10, %10 
      jz done 
      rol $1, %rdi  
      dec %r10 
      jmp loop 
 done: 
      mov %rdi, %rax
      ret
```

My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
extern unsigned long rotate(unsigned long val, unsigned long num, unsigned long direction); 

int main()
{
unsigned long v,n,d; 
v = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF; 
n = 2; 
d = 1; 

printf("%x\n ", rotate(v,n,d));    
}
```

When I compile and run, I get the value `0x7AB6FBBF`, when I am supposed to get `0x7AB6FBBF7AB6FBBF`.

Is there something wrong with my instructions not sending in `unsigned long`s or somethings?

Comment: Shouldn't it be an unsigned long long then?

Comment: You know that on most platforms a `long` is 32 bits, right?

Comment: @Sneftel: x86-64 System V has 64-bit `long`, and this code is taking args in RDI and RSI so it's pretty definitely that ABI.  ([Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812))

Comment: I changed the c code to all unsigned long longs and the results are the same

Comment: @pigsploof: x86 has `rol %cl, %rdi` and `ror %cl, %rdi`, which you can use instead of a loop.  Simply `mov` your shift count into `%ecx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes good point. Though even if the type is wide enough, `%x` is not going to print a full 64 bits.

Comment: @Sneftel: yup, I was still looking at the horribly over-complicated asm and assuming they'd gotten the C correct.  You and @zch both spotted the `%x` bug while I was posting an answer about an asm bug :P

Comment: Peter's right--all modern processors have barrel shifters that can shift and rotate many bits in a single instruction. No need to loop.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: A barrel shifter makes it possible for the single instruction to have single-cycle latency.  Even original 8086 has `ror %cl, %di`, but the imm8 shift/rotate opcodes were added  in 286 (http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html).  It wasn't until later that these instructions got really fast, but on those old CPUs shifts/rotates cost something like 1 cycle per count.  That's faster than any loop could run, especially an inefficient loop with two branches that doesn't look at flags set by `dec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%x", a)` works on `unsigned int` type. On `unsigned long` you need to use `"%lx"` as a format string.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in your asm: the loop branch in `right` does `jmp loop` instead of `jmp right`.  At least that's *one* of your bugs, IDK if there are more.  (update: @zch spotted the bug in your C which explains the truncation you're mentioning.)

This would have been easier to spot if you'd used a better name than `loop`.  e.g. `left`.

But you shouldn't be looping anyway. x86 has `rol %cl, %rdi` and `ror %cl, %rdi`, which you can use instead of a loop.  Simply `mov` your shift count into `%ecx`, like `mov %esi, %ecx`.

Comment: the reason I am using the loop is because when I try and use rol %ecx, %rsi I get an error of operand type mismatch for rol. I have to use an immediate for it to compile and I do not know why.

Comment: @pigsploof shift and rotation instructions can only use %cl or immediate as a count operand.

Comment: @pigsploof: my answer says `rol %cl, %rsi` for a reason (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html).  But `mov %esi, %ecx` can be slightly more efficient than `mov %sil, %cl` or `movzbl %sil, %ecx`, so I recommended that for the `mov`.  x86 masks the shift count anyway, so it doesn't matter whether you copy or zero the upper bits of the register, or merge into the old value of RCX.