# Does Linux/POSIX ABI define size of int?

Tags: c, linux, int, posix, abi

I know that in general case `int` size is compiler-dependant, but as Linux and other *nixes use `int` as a file descriptor and are required by POSIX to be able to send the file descriptors through UNIX sockets via `cmsghdr` structure, is there a specification that say how large is `int` exactly? Otherwise 2 different compilers could end in ABI incompatible code.

I couldn't find any definitive standard except mention in [IBM Knowledge Base](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q104610_.htm) that states that `int` is 4 bytes on UNIX and Linux on both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms.

Comment: It's more that combination of platform+OS. POSIX definitely never would define size of an int. `Otherwise 2 different compilers could end in ABI incompatible code.` Yes, and that can happen, even with the same compiler. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented

Comment: I guess POSIX by virtue of specifying the contents of `stdint.h`? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented)

Comment: [64-Bit Programming Models: Why LP64?](http://archive.opengroup.org/public/tech/aspen/lp64_wp.htm) is rather old (pre-C99, judging by the "long long, a non-standard datatype" bit), but that describes why LP64 was chosen for UNIX and UNIX-like systems.  And [here's the reasons why Windows chose LLP64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/abstract-data-models).  [64-bit computing: 64-bit data models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) is also informative, and the table provides info on the data models used by various sample platforms.

Comment: Linux also currently supports an ILP32 programming model on 64-bit platforms natively called the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  It is kinda the same as the x86 (i386) ABI, except that it can take advantage of the x86-64 ABI with the exception that you are still limited to 4 GiB of memory.  However, [whether it sticks around or not](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/12/10/1145) remains to be seen. [Debian's "popularity contest" x32 stats](https://popcon.debian.org/stat/sub-x32.png) indicates rare usage of x32, and the long LKML discussion suggests maintenance is difficult.