# segmentations in x86 vs segmentations in compiler under linux

Tags: linux, x86, compiler-construction

I read a book about segmentations under x86, and I know gcc compiler also use segments. I'm new to this topic. I just wondering if segmentations in compiler will be mapped to segmentations in x86 cpu.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wondering if segmentations in compiler will be mapped to segmentations in x86 cpu.

The 32 bits [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) (so i386 to i686 and compatible) had segment registers. The 64 bits [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) (used in most laptops or desktops in 2020), no more (that is, they have a different role and are used differently in *long mode*). Look into [y86](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ereeves.92/CSE2421sp13/PracticeProblemsY86.pdf) and [simulators](https://www.simn.me/js-y86/). For [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) (i.e. tablets or [RaspBerryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)), things are different.

On Linux/x86-64 segment registers are nearly  unused in [user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) land (except for thread local storage).

If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile a C program  `foo.c` [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -fverbose-asm -O2 -S foo.c -o foo.s` then look inside the generated `foo.s` assembler file.

### So in practice, not.

For more read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), and wikipage about [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and [application binary interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

> I know gcc compiler also use segments

### no, but [ELF files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) have segments and sections.

Then refer to [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812/841108) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/). Read the [ABI specification](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-draft.pdf) and the [Linux Assembler HowTo](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/index.html). Consider also using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) if you want to generate machine code at runtime. Or [generate C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) at runtime (see my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) as an example), compile it as a plugin or [shared object](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), and use [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html).

You might look into the source code of simple open source C compilers such as [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) or [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) (and later inside [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)).

Comment: The segment registers DS, ES, etc, do still exist in long mode, but their functionality is much reduced and they're rarely used explicitly, except that FS and GS are often used for things like thread-local storage.

Comment: The question was tagged Linux

Comment: Yes, and GNU/Linux uses segment registers the same way in both i386 and x86-64: flat memory model plus FS as a TLS base.  (Or GS for 32-bit code).  So the fact that x86-64 neutered segmentation and enforces a flat memory model had no effect on how Linux used them.  And more importantly, it's just plain wrong to say they're gone.  You can still `mov ds, eax` in user-space and it will still segfault if you do that with a selector value outside the GDT or LDT. And it's *necessary* for CS to have a selector value that selects a 64-bit code segment descriptor in the GDT (or LDT) for x86-64 to work.

Comment: TL:DR: I think your first paragraph should probably be removed because it doesn't aid understanding of your later points.  It also contradicts your 2nd paragraph (stating that a segment reg is used for TLS, despite earlier saying they don't exist.)