# Changes to register within a function call

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

If I pass two arguments to a function as follows:

```
loop:
    mov my_array(,%r8d,4), %edi
    mov $2,                %esi
    call some_function
    ...
```

Do I need to 're-add' the value `2` to `%edi` every time I call the function if it's static? In other words, can I assume that `%esi` will not change in a function, or do I need to re-set it before each time I call that function? What's the preferred way to do this in a System V ABI?

Comment: What does the ABI say about this register?  Are you linking this with C code?  What C compiler generated that code?

Comment: @old_timer no I'm just playing around with assembly, i.e., hand-written no compiler.

Comment: hm, @NateEldredge what does callee-saved mean in this case? Is saved the same thing as "preserved" ? In that the function that is called is not supposed to touch them? Also, could you please link the the page or where it says that?

Comment: Wait a second, this is 64-bit code.  (Please use the [tag:x86-64] tag.)  On x86-64, rsi and rdi (including their low halves esi, edi) are NOT required to be preserved across function calls.  You will need to reload them after calling the function.  [ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented) Figure 3.4, page 23 in my copy.

Comment: Of course, if you have written `some_function` by hand in assembler, then what it does with those registers is whatever you wrote it to do.  If it doesn't need to be called by C code, then it is up to you whether to follow the ABI calling conventions or some other.

Comment: Arg-passing registers are call-clobbered in every register-arg calling convention (at least for x86, and generally true across other ISA's calling conventions).