# GAS Assembler print float point

Tags: floating-point, gnu-assembler

I’m reading a book on how to program in assembly using NASM and having problem building a program that print 3.1400000.

Code might have a few problems like, using wrong statement in
`section  .data pi: .float 3.14` 
should be of type double quad but I have no idea which pseudo-op
maps to that; I tried .dq however doesn’t works like that.

Also i’ve read that call stack need to be align before programs start, I hope that using base pointer solves that problem otherwise without program prints a segment error.

One other note for learning purposes i’m using GAS with Intel syntax hence i’m not sure syntax mapping below is correct.

Code:

```
#fmtflt.s
.intel_syntax noprefix
.extern printf 

.section .data
    pi: .float 3.14

.section .rodata
    fmtflt: .ascii  "%1f\12\0"

.section .text
    .globl main
        main:
            push    rbp
            mov     rbp, rsp
            mov     rax, 0             # set total numers xmm register  
            movq    xmm0, [pi]          # set content pi to
            mov     rdi, offset fmtflt  # set address format string
            call    printf              # call printf function
            mov     rsp, rbp
            pop     rbp
            ret
```

Compile:
gcc -no-pie -o fmtflt  fmtflt.s

Output:

actual: 0.000000
expected: 3.140000

Can anyone fill in missing piece such that program prints expected output ?

Comment: What do you think `mov     rax, 0             # set total numers xmm register` does?

Comment: That was a typo suppose to be 1 however I had to change data type to .double.

Answer (score 1):

> using wrong statement in section  .data pi: .float 3.14 should be of type double quad but I have no idea which pseudo-op maps to that;

Use `.double` to assemble an 8-byte double-precision floating point value.  See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dFloat.html#i386_002dFloat.

Then, as Joseph points out, look at the line:

```
mov     rax, 0             # set total numers xmm register
```

As the comment says, `rax` should be set to the total number of xmm (SSE) registers being used to pass arguments.  See Figure 3.4 of [the x86-64 SysV ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented), which is the authoritative reference for calling conventions on systems like Linux that use it.  You are passing 1 argument in an xmm register (on the very next line), so set `rax` to `1`, not `0`.  The instruction `mov eax, 1` has the same effect (because moves into 32-bit registers zero the upper half of the 64-bit register) and is one less byte.

With those changes, the program correctly prints `3.140000` for me.

> Also i’ve read that call stack need to be align before programs start, I hope that using base pointer solves that problem otherwise without program prints a segment error.

Yes, you got that part right.