# Get C values for Att assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I have this code in c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int64_t myprintf(char* e, int64_t i,...);

int main()
{
    
    myprintf("%s",'H','e','l','l');

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and i compile with this command `gcc -no-pie -g fnt.c mp.s -o hello.out`

there is my ATT function :

```
    movq 16(%rsp),%rax  /* format */
    movq 24(%rsp),%rbx  /* 1er param */
    movq 32(%rsp),%r8   /* 2e param */
    movq 40(%rsp),%r9   /* 3e param */
    movq 48(%rsp),%r10  /* 4e param */
```

and i cant get my C values for example --> get 'e' in %rbx ...

Thank you !

Comment: What is your calling convension? Writing the function `fnt` in C and seeing how it is conveted to assembly via your compiler (`-S` option is useful for gcc) will be helpful.

Comment: Or just compiling your `main` function and seeing how the arguments are stored will be useful.

Comment: didnt really get what you want me to do

Comment: I assume you're following SysV calling conventions, since they prevail on most platforms that use gcc/gas.  You seem to be assuming that all parameters are passed on the stack, but that's not correct - the first 6 are in registers.  See [the ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented).

Comment: MikeCAT is suggesting you look at [the assembly generated by the compiler for `main`](https://godbolt.org/z/WYnYd1), and observe that it is putting all the arguments in registers, none on the stack.

Comment: Neither of the mainstream x86-64 calling conventions pass args on the stack, they use registers for the first 6 integer/pointer args (or on Windows, first 4 args)