# Assembler program to swap contents of registers

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm trying to do a real simple assembler program to swap the contents of registers. This is what i've tried:

```
movq (%rcx), %rax
movq (%rbx), %rdx
movq %rdx, (%rcx)
movq %rax, (%rbx)
ret
```

It gives me segmentation fault.

Here is an example of a working program in c:

```
void swap(int64_t *a, int64_t *b) {
    int64_t c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting each of these instructions to do?  And which one is causing the fault?

Comment: You are assuming that `rcx` and `rbx` contain the required pointer values. Do they?

Comment: How are you compiling your assembly? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [example], please.

Comment: The title says "swap contents of registers" yet the examples are about memory locations. To swap registers you can use `xchg`.

Comment: Godbolt produces a different assembly (register usage, -O3 optimization): https://godbolt.org/z/dYYeYYrz1

Comment: It is processor and system dependent. C does not not mandate *how* an implementation passes data to functions, or in which registers, or if any.

Comment: Have you tried looking at compiler output for the working C function?  That should show you which registers your pointer args arrive in, and which registers you can use as temporaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

You neglected to mention whether you're compiling for Microsoft/Win x64 or for the System V AMD64 ABI [or for something else entirely].

You are using AT&T asm syntax, so I'm assuming you want the SysV calling convention.  (Since tools like GCC and GAS are more common on Linux / MacOS.  But if you're using MinGW w64 on Windows then you'll want the Windows convention.)

---

**You're assuming the args are in: `%rcx` and `%rbx`**. This does *not* correspond with *either* convention [although it is somewhat closer to the MS ABI]

For System V AMD64 ABI (e.g. Linux, BSD, MacOS), the first two args are passed in `%rdi` and `%rsi` respectively. And, *not* in `%rdx` and `%rcx` (which are for the 3rd and 4th args).

You can always use `%rax` and `%rdx` as temp regs because `%rax` holds the function return value and `%rdx` is an arg reg so caller won't expect them to be preserved.

So, you want:

```
# Non-Windows
movq (%rdi),%rax
movq (%rsi),%rdx
movq %rdx,(%rdi)
movq %rax,(%rsi)
ret
```

For MS 64 bit, the arg registers are: `%rcx, %rdx, %r8, %r9`

So, you'd want:

```
# Windows
movq (%rcx),%rax
movq (%rdx),%r8
movq %r8,(%rcx)
movq %rax,(%rdx)
ret
```

Comment: Huh, I'd been thinking the official title on https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf was x86-64, but actually you're right, the cover page calls it "System V Application Binary Interface
AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement"  IDK why they moved away from x86-64 in v0.9 of the ABI (many years ago).  (In case anyone's wondering, it's technically a "supplement" to the generic SysV ABI doc which covers some general ELF stuff I think. 
 [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812))