Fortran real(REAL80) and C __float80 size
Consider the following C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int16_t   i16;
  __float80 r80;
  printf("size of 16 bit integer: %u\nsize of 80 bit real: %u\n",
         sizeof(i16) * 8, sizeof(r80) * 8);
  return 0;
}

and the following Fortran code (I know using integer literals for kind parameters is not portable):
program test
  implicit none
  integer(2) :: i16
  real(10)   :: r80
  print '("size of 16 bit integer: ", i0, /, "size of 80 bit real: ", i0)', &
    &   storage_size(i16), storage_size(r80)
end program test

Using gcc and gfortran, both will print:
size of 16 bit integer: 16
size of 80 bit real: 128

Question: Why 80 bit floating points are 128 bits wide?
I think it relates to memory alignment and optimization. But then why 16 bit integers are 16 bits wide?
P.S. Actually, this is related to my other question.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented

@steve: I have those documents, but did't read it. I'll check them. thank you.

Well ultimately you've answered your own question - Real80 is not portable so it can be anything. But it looks like to me that you are on a machine that doesn't support 80 bit reals, so somebody in the compiler team has tried to be helpful by providing a kind which is at least 80 bits wide -c.f. the behaviour of Selected_real_kind.

@IanBush kind=10 in gfortran on x86 is definitely a 80 bits real, but stored on 128 bits (48 bits are unused).

@PierU Yes. But irrelevant. I am not talking about what is or is not implemented in hardware. I am talking about what the symbol Real80 refers to as defined by an implementation. They are not the same thing. Ceci n'est pas une pipe

Noye that the meaning of kind numbers like 2 and 10 are completely system dependent. On a different compiler or a different cpu architecture with the same compiler they may mean something else or may not exist at all. But you probably cannot get an 80-real without directly using the kind value 10.

@IanBush Iwas answering to "it looks like to me that you are on a machine that doesn't support 80 bit reals". On the contrary, their machine (which is apparently a x86 one) does support 80 bits reals.

You may like to know that storage_size(r80) is not defined to return the size of r80, but something else.

@IanBush : I have Core i5. Every x86 > 486 has internal FPU compatible with 80387 and have extend 80 bit precision. I think steve's answer is correct and this 128 bit stroage size is ABI related. Thanks for Ceci n'est pas une pip.

@francescalus : see this. I think I didn't get your point. Could you please tell more on something else.

As noted in the documentation you link, the "something else" is given in "The result value is the size expressed in bits for an element of an array that has the dynamic type and type parameters of [r80]". This isn't the same thing as r80.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly I know. That is not my point. The symbol real80 as implemented by a compiler is not the same thing as a piece of hardware. There may be a mapping between the symbol and an actual piece of hardware, but in this case no standard guarantees this. And that is essentially the thing you are worrying about.

You have answered your own question: this is a choice of the gcc/gfortran compiler on the x86 platform to have a better alignment. real(kind=10) is a 80 bits floating point, stored on 128 bits (48 bits are unused). (Edit: as mentioned in the comments, the value 10 is not portable in itself, another compiler may use another value to select 80 bits reals)
Such a choice results from a balance between performances (alignment on 128 bits boundaries) and storage (37,5% wasted). As any choice, it is questionable. Note that storing 16 bits integers on 32 bit boundaries would mean 50% storage waste, which would be totally unacceptable.

Thank you for your answer. About using 10 or other literals for kind parameters, I mentioned that it is not portable. But for alignment, I saw it in structure field padding, array element padding, .. for greater performance. But padding a single variable looks strange to me. From steve comment on original post, It seems an ABI choice. I'll check x86_64 SysV ABI one I have time. I'll update the post if I find exact description for this behaviour.

See Section 3.1 in x86_64-SysV-psABI.pdf.  Figure 3.1 clearly shows the ABI's choice of 128 bits of storage for an Intel 80-bit extended double entity.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly This is not padding, this is part of the definition of what is a real(kind=10) for the compiler.

Thank you @steve, this is what I want, Could you please add an answer, so I could accept it.
